# Can I authenticate app automatically with MDM?

Tags: iphone, ios, mdm

I am writing an iOS app that will run on iPhones that are enrolled with MDM (Airwatch or Mobile Iron)

Is there a way to authenticate the app with a server automatically, so once the app is opened for the first time it will "log in" as the MDM user?

I don't want to use deprecated or private APIs, so using UDID for authenticating the device is not an option.

Thanks,
Ariel

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 6 it's not possible.

a) You don't have access in your app to any info which can uniquely represent you to the server

b) You don't have access to any authenticating info (keys, password and etc) which are shared between app and MDM.

For iOS 7 they introduced couple of new features (I can't discuss them, because they are under NDA).
However, if you go and watch videos from Apple WWDC 2013, you will see improvements to MDM which they did and you will see a way how it will be possible.

Comment: the NDA does not apply anymore. The docs are public now. But do not cover this scenario. Could you just give a hint into the right direction here?

Comment: @RaduSimionescu Ugh... I didn't touch MDM for quite a while. As I remember at some point (iOS 7) they introduced a feature that MDM can set some settings to iOS app. It worked only for Managed apps. You can look through their document and there will be something like Managed App Settings or something like that. So you can push some secret (password or keys) to your app for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually possible even on iOS 5 & 6 with MobileIron's AppConnect solution. If you are a customer, all of the details, including APIs and documentation, are available at http://support.mobileiron.com/appconnect.  Public information is at http://www.mobileiron.com/appconnect.